# Axios request in Vue.js method working when launched from "mounted()" but not when launched from html <form>

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

When I authenticate to **Laravel Passport** backend with **Nuxt.js** like below, it works and I get a token:

```
mounted() {
  this.axiosGetToken()
}
```

But, if I run the method with a `button` in a `form`, like this:

```
<form @submit="axiosGetToken()">
    <button type="submit">Axios login</button>
</form>
```

Then, I get the status `(canceled)` for the **Laravel** page in the *Network* tab of my browser developer's tool.

The method looks like this:

```
axiosGetToken() {
  const url = 'http://laravel.test/oauth/token'
  const params = {
    client_id: 2,
    client_secret: 'S0gpcgfIDgbvIHCL3jIhSICAiTsTUMOR0k5mdaCi',
    grant_type: 'password',
    username: 'me@home.com',
    password: '1qaz@WSX'
  }
  const headers = {
  }
  this.$axios
    .post(url, params, headers)
    .then(response => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(response => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line
        console.log(response)
    })
},
```

What's wrong with this form ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `prevent` modifier :

```
<form @submit.prevent="axiosGetToken()">
    <button type="submit">Axios login</button>
</form>
```

by default the `submit` event try to reload the page and searching an action from the back-end in order to run it, so the `prevent` modifier will prevent the action and allows the running of the js event handler.

Comment: Thanks! Why is that ?

Comment: you're welcome, please check my edited answer i added some explanation

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, if you use a form with a button of type="submit", when pressing that button, it will use the default client behavior and send a request to the form action URL, adding a prevent will stop that behavior.

Although it is a valid answer, I would suggest adding a @click="axiosGetToken()" on the button.

```
    <form>
        <button type="button" @click="axiosGetToken()">Axios login</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Great, but then why keeping the`<form>` ?

Comment: it is up to you to keep the form or not, usually, I keep the form so that the code is clear, meaning, you know there should be a form that is supposed to submit some data to an endpoint, and for styling purposes aswell.